# HQL of a many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I got a language and a country class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name="Country.findLanguagesByCountryId",query="???")
})
public class Country implements IEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;       

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Language.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "country_language", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "lid")})
    private Set<Language> languages;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "languages")
public class Language implements IEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

As you can see country has a list of languages but language doesn't have a list of countries.

I need the HQL which should find languages by country id.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer

```
select language from Country country
inner join country.languages language 
where country.id=?1
```